# Reply to sender - PHP email

Tags: php, forms, email, reply

Here is my code for a email form. It works well, it sends to my email. But how can i make it so i can reply to the email that i received from the form? Would you be able to edit my code and put it in because im a BIG php noobie. many thanks!

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "adamgoredesign@gmail.com";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);

header('Location: contact_thankyou.html');

?>
```

Comment: This code is susceptible to SMTP header injections because the POST field `name` is not sanitized.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you need to set the `headers` to be able to pass the [sender email:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

fx:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

so your code will look something like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "adamgoredesign@gmail.com";
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: contact_thankyou.html');
```

Note: I never tested myself, I normally use smtp.mail class to do all this for me, since it is more easy, clean... [just check it out...](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

then it will look something like this:

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->AddAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->AddCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->AddBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: well i tried your code. but now my email wont send at all. so not sure whats going on there.

I'd rather not use PHPmainer for this one, but cheers for the link

Comment: As in, i don't receive at email all together.

Comment: This only works for me, if I omit the last argument (`, "From: " . $name`)