# Reply to email not working in php

Tags: php, email

I want to replace default webmaster email from my email it's not working in php script.
I have tried reply-to but it's not working
This is my php code.

```
$headers= "Reply-To: my@email.com\n";

mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions about this, I suggest you to [check these answers out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418751/reply-to-sender-php-email)

Comment: Is `$headers` already defined?

Comment: This is my code.

 $headers = 'From: admin@adventureclicknblog.com' . "\r\n" ;
 $headers .= 'Reply-To: admin@adventureclicknblog.com' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;
 charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

 When I send email from this script it's send but reply-to email come with this email webmaster email 
clicknbl@rsj17.rhostjh.com 
I dont know how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple structure (source: [PHP.net - mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php))

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about your php-version, but mine doesn't like spaces when concatenetating with `.=`

try to remove the space here:

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: my@email.com\n";
```

so you get:

```
$headers.= "Reply-To: my@email.com\n";
```

(giving us information about whether you are getting an error-message and if so, which one - would have helped quite a lot, when my suggestion is right)