# php mail reply subject

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, reply

So I managed to use "reply-to" and set an email to be replied to, however I'm wondering if its possible to change the subject of the email after its replied? instead of Re: 'Original Subject'?

```
$header = "From: " . $from ."\r\nReply-to: " . $email . "\r\n";
```

maybe something like this?
P.S. this 2nd code doesn't work, its just to help me get my point across

```
$header = "From: " . $from ."\r\nReply-to: " . $email . "\r\nReply-subject: Company Support Message\r\n";
```

Comment: I guess, you can do it by using `$mail->Subject` but not sure. Have you tried using that piece of code?

Comment: that 2nd code is not actually code, I'm just trying to change the subject of the replied email, different from the subject of the 1st email

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reply to sender - PHP email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418751/reply-to-sender-php-email)

Comment: See [RFC2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt). There's no such thing as a Reply-Subject: preset (AFAIK).

Comment: yea I realised, so essentially there's no answer to this question